# Merge 2 hashes recursively with jinja2/ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to merge 2 hashes in ansible, but I'm running into problems. The hash is mostly merged, but the lists inside are not.

I'm using the combine filter for the merge:

```
config_hash: "{{ inventory_config | combine(host_config, recursive=True, list_merge='append_rp') }}"
```

Here are the two hashes/dicts I'd like to merge:

```
inventory_config:
  exoscale:
    inventory_name: test_inventory
    security_groups: 
      - name: rancher
        state: present
        rules:
          - port: 22
            cidr: "1.2.3.4/32"
            type: egress
          - port: 80
            cidr: "0.0.0.0/32"
            type: egress

host_config:
  exoscale:
    name: host
    disk_size: 25 GiB
    security_groups: 
      - name: rancher
        state: added
        rules:
          - port: 21
            cidr: "1.2.3.4/32"
            type: ingress
          - port: 8080
            cidr: "0.0.0.0/32"
            type: ingress
```

The result:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [instance] => {
    "config_hash": {
        "exoscale": {
            "disk_size": "25 GiB",
            "inventory_name": "test_inventory",
            "name": "host",
            "security_groups": [
                {
                    "name": "rancher",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                            "port": 22,
                            "type": "egress"
                        },
                        {
                            "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                            "port": 80,
                            "type": "egress"
                        }
                    ],
                    "state": "present"
                },
                {
                    "name": "rancher",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                            "port": 21,
                            "type": "ingress"
                        },
                        {
                            "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                            "port": 8080,
                            "type": "ingress"
                        }
                    ],
                    "state": "added"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The result I wanted:

```
"config_hash": {
    "exoscale": {
        "disk_size": "25 GiB",
        "inventory_name": "test_inventory",
        "name": "host",
        "security_groups": [
            {
                "name": "rancher",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                        "port": 22,
                        "type": "egress"
                    },
                    {
                        "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                        "port": 80,
                        "type": "egress"
                    },
                    {
                        "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                        "port": 21,
                        "type": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                        "port": 8080,
                        "type": "ingress"
                    }
                ],
                "state": "added"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried some other options, and it seems that "list_merge='append_rp'" can combine lists of simple items but not hashes.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would those two dictionary merge together when they are actually different  (one is `state: added`, the other is `state: present`? Because of that and the complexity of those kind of tasks (what if a field is different, what value should win, what if the list inside a property have duplicated values, etc.), there is no built-in easy way to achieve this. And as your question is currently written, you have to realise that answerer(s) are going to take assumption that will probably not match your desired use case in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
In this case "present" means that the security_group should only be created and "added" means that the security_group should be created and the host should be added to the security_group.
When merged, in the final dict the value "added" would be right.

So if a value is present in both dicts the "host_config" should have more weight, so it overwrites the values in the "inventory_config".
Lists should get merged and elements should be appended, except if the exact same list object already exists.

Comment: host_config could have state:added or state: present ok?   and inventory_config could have state: added ? or only state: present?

Comment: another question could you have for same name, state:added and state:present in same config variable?

Comment: the idea is that inventory_config.exoscale.security_group can be a security_group for all instances in one inventory... like "default" rule, if you add state: added to the default rule on inventory level, every virtual machine should be added to the default rule... all other rules should be defined in the host_config or group_config... but everything in host_config overwrites every other rule, except for lists

host_config won't really have "state: present" only "state: added" 
inventory_config mostly has "state: present" and rarely "state: added"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is complex, i suggest you to use a custom filter:

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py** and the filter **custom**)

myfilters.py in folder filter_plugins:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'custom': self.custom
        }

    def custom(self, invent, host):
        isecu = invent['exoscale']['security_groups']
        hsecu = host['exoscale']['security_groups']
        inventory_name = invent['exoscale']['inventory_name']
        name = host['exoscale']['name']
        disk_size = host['exoscale']['disk_size']


        security_groups = []
        
        inames_present =  [elem['name'] for elem in isecu]

        # if you have present and added in inventory_config uncomment next lines
        # inames_present = []
        # inames_added = [] 
        # for elem in isecu:
        #     if elem['state'] == 'present':
        #         inames_present.append(elem['name'])
        #     else:
        #         inames_added.append(elem['name']) 
   
        for it in hsecu:
            secuname = it['name']
            state = it['state']
            if secuname in inames_present:
                if state == 'present': #overwrite data
                    rules = it['rules']
                else: #merge
                    rules = it['rules'] + isecu[inames_present.index(secuname)]['rules']
            else:
                rules = it['rules']
                state = 'added'
                               
            security_groups.append({'name': secuname, 'rules': rules, 'state': state})
            
        result = {'exoscale': {'disk_size': disk_size, 'name': name, 'inventory_name': inventory_name, 'security_groups': security_groups}}
        #print(result)
        return result
```

the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    inventory_config:
      exoscale:
        inventory_name: test_inventory
        security_groups: 
          - name: rancher
            state: present
            rules:
              - port: 22
                cidr: "1.2.3.4/32"
                type: egress
              - port: 80
                cidr: "0.0.0.0/32"
                type: egress               
    host_config:
      exoscale:
        name: host
        disk_size: 25 GiB
        security_groups: 
          - name: rancher
            state: added
            rules:
              - port: 21
                cidr: "1.2.3.4/32"
                type: ingress
              - port: 8080
                cidr: "0.0.0.0/32"
                type: ingress
  tasks:
    - name: set variable
      set_fact:
        config_hash: "{{ inventory_config | custom(host_config)  }}"
    - name: Display
      debug:
        var: config_hash
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "config_hash": {
        "exoscale": {
            "disk_size": "25 GiB",
            "inventory_name": "test_inventory",
            "name": "host",
            "security_groups": [
                {
                    "name": "rancher",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                            "port": 21,
                            "type": "ingress"
                        },
                        {
                            "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                            "port": 8080,
                            "type": "ingress"
                        },
                        {
                            "cidr": "1.2.3.4/32",
                            "port": 22,
                            "type": "egress"
                        },
                        {
                            "cidr": "0.0.0.0/32",
                            "port": 80,
                            "type": "egress"
                        }
                    ],
                    "state": "added"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You have an idea how to use a custom filter in ansible.
You just adapt the code python.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will try it out :)

Comment: @joggie dont forget yo close your question by validating and upvoting the answer..